# Recursion inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, recursion

I have repetition in loop - when `isAllowed` = true - then continue next iteration, but when `isAllowed` is false - then the program should repeat generate random positions, coordinates and check if the `isAllowed` until is true.

How to make recursion in that loop to achieve this objective?

```cs
foreach (var fleet in groupedFleetsbySpaceshipCounts)
{
    var randomPositionX = new Random().Next(0, 9);
    var randomPositionY = new Random().Next(0, 9);

    var cords = int.Parse(randomPositionX.ToString() + randomPositionY);
    map.Location[cords].ActualFleetPosition = fleet.Key[i];
    var isAllowed = IsPositionAllowed(map, cords);
    if (isAllowed)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        randomPositionX = new Random().Next(0, 9);
        randomPositionY = new Random().Next(0, 9);

        cords = int.Parse(randomPositionX.ToString() + randomPositionY);
        map.Location[cords].ActualFleetPosition = fleet.Key[i];
        isAllowed = IsPositionAllowed(map, cords);
        if (isAllowed)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            //recursion
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `var randomPositionX = new Random().Next(0, 9);
            var randomPositionY = new Random().Next(0, 9);` don't do this, declare the randoms outside the scope you have them as static (class level) and then use them in your calling code.

Comment: I suggest you should use simple for and move/increase the iterator/indexer when you want to do the next iteration unless it automatically repeats the loop.

Comment: You should not create new `Random` instances in a loop - you also do not need distinct instances to generate 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```cs
var random = new Random();
foreach (var fleet in groupedFleetsbySpaceshipCounts)
{
    int coords;
    do {
        int randomPositionX = random.Next(0, 9);
        int randomPositionY = random.Next(0, 9);

        coords = 10 * randomPositionX + randomPositionY;
    } while (!IsPositionAllowed(map, coords));

    map.Location[coords].ActualFleetPosition = fleet.Key[i++];
}
```

I.e., you don't need a recursion (i.e., a method that calls itself), but another loop nested inside the first one.

Note that the max value of `random.Next` is exclusive. So, if you want numbers up to `9` you must use an upper value of `10`. Also, if the lower value is `0`, you can simply write `random.Next(10)`.

It is important to create the `Random` object only once, because otherwise you might end up having different random objects generating the same pseudo random sequence. Using a static field in your class is even a better option than using a local variable

```cs
private static readonly _random = new Random();
```

Comment: yes - exactly - it solve the issue - some syntax improvement and it will work

Comment: But why here is operation = 10 * randompositionX + randomPositionY?
The intention here - concat as string

Comment: example if a = 5 and b = 7 - then cords should be 57, but at all it doesn't matter - coords should be between 0 and 99

Comment: Well, 10 * 5 + 7 = 57. Isn't it? If you have coords up to 99 then use 100 * x + y (= 507). However, you could use a 2-dimensional array instead: `T[,] a = new T[With, Height];` and access it with `a[x, y]`. that would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do the trick (edited with some of your comments, I didn't want to enter on other things rather than the question):

```
var random = new Random();    
foreach (var fleet in groupedFleetsbySpaceshipCounts)
    {
        do
        {
            var randomPositionX = random.Next(0, 9);
            var randomPositionY = random.Next(0, 9);

            //Im not sure how you're managing this 'coords' map, but gonna just go to the point 
            var cords = int.Parse(randomPositionX.ToString() + randomPositionY);
            map.Location[cords].ActualFleetPosition = fleet.Key[i];
        } while (!IsPositionAllowed(map, cords));
        i++;
    }
```

If you want 'cords' variable to be available outside the do...while loop you can safely declare it outside the loop (even better, outside the foreach).

Comment: You are sure? - the cords variable is inside scope, so it's undefined outside {} in do while

Comment: your solution worked as base - thank You! - there is need to define cords one level up.